# How to send a delayed response inside Scala actor

Tags: scala, actor

Non-actor class sends a synchronous message to actor like this:

```
val response = WorkData !? "hello"
```

If i want to respond to this message right away, than i will do this:

```
receive {
  case "hello" => reply("world")
}
```

But if i need to reply some time in the future, than
how do i store the caller reference, and send the reply after that?

Comment: I think if you want to reply in the future, you need to send an asynchronous message (not a synchronous one with `?!`), and the easiest way for your actor to hand over a response when it's ready is when the sender is itself an actor, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, i need a lot of refactoring, to make the sender an actor. I thought i can get a "future" reference for sender somehow, and use it to send answer back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference to the current caller is stored at `sender`. E.g., it's perfectly valid to replace

```
receive {
  case "hello" => reply("world")
}
```

with

```
receive {
  case "hello" => sender ! "world"
}
```

You can store this ref hereafter in the mutable variable, or pass recursively through the actor's loop.

Comment: The sender is not an actor, i think i can't send message back via sender than? Or i'm wrong about this?

Comment: you can send a message back to a non-actor in Scala 2.8

Answer (score 4):

I generally store the sender reference to use it later.

```
receive {
  case "hello" => 
    val otherParty = sender
    // more receives, etc
    // ...
    otherParty ! "world"   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just spawning an anonymous actor that processes the message and respond when it's ready? This way the receiver just acts as a dispatcher. This does not need a mutable variable to store anything since you are using a closure here.

```
import scala.actors.Actor                                                              
import scala.actors.Actor._

case class Message(msg: String)

class MyReceiver extends Actor {
  def act() {
    react {
      case Message(msg) =>
        actor {
          sender ! process(msg)
        }   
    }   
  }

  def process(msg: String): String =
    "Result: " + msg 
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = new MyReceiver
    a.start()

    val res = a !? Message("foo")
    println(res)
  }
}
```

Regards, raichoo